# Spring WebClient: avoid use of .block() when non REST triggered

Tags: spring-integration, spring-webflux, spring-jms

Spring Boot JMS/Integration micro service listen to event/messages coming from a queue, after a message is processed it will be sent via REST call to an other micro service.
Is it possible to avoid the use of `.block()` as follow:

```
public ClientResponse post(DispatcherMessage mqMessageBody) {
    return dispatcherWebClient.post()
            .uri(PROCESS_ENGINE_ENDPOINT)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .bodyValue(mqMessageBody)
            .exchange();
            //.block();
}
```

in other words can the service be started using Netty instead of Tomcat?

I've noticed that if I don't call `.block()` there will be no incoming request on the second service.

Comment: Try to use `subscribe()` instead of `block()`

Comment: why not you map the response and use another webclient to pass it to other micro service? then there will be no need of block or subscribe

Comment: Return a Mono<MyObject> instead of the direct object reference.

Comment: you should post full code to get help quickly and more precisely

Comment: @Artem Bilian, subscribe() works, if you post it as answer I will accept, thanks!